# How can I run macros in XLSM file from C#.net code?

Tags: .net, epplus

I have 1 XLSM file which contains macros and I want to run macros from my C#.net application.

My C#.net application  write some cells value in the same file and on the basis of theses cells few other cells where macros is written get updated with final values and my final goal is to read those cells.

Can it be possible with EPPlus?

If you need any other information from me please let me know.

I have tried to achieve it with other third party tool but I am not able to run the macros from my C#.net application.

How can I achieve this?

Regards,

Nitin Sharma